# PHP HTML Excel Export Not working

Tags: php, html, excel, export

PHP HTML Excel Export Not working, the exported excel file showing blank when i open in MS Excel 2016 Version .Before it was working fine when i using MS EXCEL 2013 and lower version to open the file. The cod used to convert html to .Xls is here

```
<?php
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.xls");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no code here that __converts__ html to xls; all you have is code that tells the browser that it's going to get xls, but you're not showing how you convert html to xls

Comment: Note that only the last `Content Type` heading will be used, ony one content type heading is sent to a browser, and that will be the last one that you define

Comment: I need to convert  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
   </tr>
</table>   To Excel and also need to open in MS Excel 2016

Comment: Even edited, there is nothing here that will actually __convert__ html to xls; just send html data, but tell the browser that it's an xls file.... that doesn't actually convert anything, it's like putting a "Ferrari" sticker on your "Subaru", it doesn't really change your Subaru into a Ferrari.... and in the case of MS Excel, most recent versions complain when the actual format of the file (html markup in your case) doesn't match the extension (xls)

Comment: If you want to actually convert html to xls, then you need to use an appropriate library

Comment: Please give me a suggestion to convert  a simple  html file to xls and also need to open in Microsoft excel 2016

Comment: Consider using a library such as my own [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library, though better to build the data as Excel directly rather than converting

Answer (score 1):

Right click on downloaded file in Windows Explorer, then Properties, then check the Unlock checkbox. The file will then open as before. I found no better solution so far.