# How to download HTML table to Excel sheet - PHP

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to download a table in the PHP page to an excel sheet using the below code.

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=name.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");
```

which does the job of exporting the table data on that page to an excel sheet and downloading it as a .xls file. But upon opening it give me a prompt like the below :

[image]

Can someone explain to me what caused this error? Should I change anything in the code. ?

Comment: It's like when I say "I am the emperor of china", but in reality I am not... through the header you claim, that your document is excel, but in reality it isn't.

Comment: This has been asked several times, e.g. [PHP HTML Excel Export Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852017/php-html-excel-export-not-working) -- people attempting to do what you do. It will not be Excel just because you want it to, and there is no "fix" for this. Either export to CSV (easier) or use a library that handles the format conversion, e.g. [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can you this package to export your data into excel sheet/csv.

- https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$dataValue[] = array(
            'Header 1' => "value 1",
            'Header 2' => "Value 2",
        );
if (empty($dataValue)) {
   $dataValue[] = array('Header 1' => 'No data available in table');
}
$csv->output('file_name_to_save.csv', $dataValue, array('Header 1','Header 2'));
```